# Amending all Charts

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have a workbook that has several worksheets, each having several charts.

These all record progress of various functions, so the X-axis is date.

Obviously, the end of that axis should be today's date - OK, for visual effect, say a week today.  So it needs to be changed every day.

Excel produced this Macro, that works just fine - on one chart.

```
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Overall").Activate
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).Select
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = Int(Now()) + 7
    Application.CommandBars("Format Object").Visible = False
```

How do I change that to make it do EVERY chart on EVERY worksheet ?

```
    Do for each Sheet - how do I do that ?
        Do for each Chart - how do I do that ?
            Do the Biz - code as above, but quotes replaced by what ?
        Loop until what ?
    Loop until what ?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub update()
     Dim ws As Worksheet, cht As ChartObject, n As Integer, dt As Date
     dt = Date + 7
     For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
          For Each cht In ws.ChartObjects
              cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = dt
              n = n + 1
          Next
     Next
     MsgBox n & " charts updated to " & Format(dt, "yyyy-mm-dd"), vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: B R I L - Y U N T  !   
Thank you very much indeed !