# Amending all Charts 2

Tags: excel, vba, excel-charts

Further to my
[Amending all Charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69054130/amending-all-charts)

- very kindly solved by @CDP1802 - for which, again, many thanks -

Silly me . . .
I also need to extend the lines that appear on the Charts, i.e.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Option Explicit
Dim ws As Worksheet, cht As ChartObject, n As Integer, dt As Date
Dim myLastRow As Integer, myRow As Integer
    
Sheets("Record").Select

' Go to last entry
myLastRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
myLastRow = Range("H" & myLastRow).End(xlUp).Row
Range("D" & myLastRow).Select   ' Don't ask !
    
' Extend Column A so that the last entry is a week from today.
'  Also extend predictions

myRow = myLastRow
Do Until Range("A" & myRow) >= Now() + 7
    myRow = myRow + 1
    Range("A" & myRow) = Range("A" & myRow - 1) + 1
    If myRow > myLastRow + 1 Then
        Range("B" & myRow & ":G" & myRow) = Range("B" & myRow - 1 & ":G" & myRow - 1)
    End If
Loop


dt = Date + 7

 For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each cht In ws.ChartObjects
          cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = dt

          For every Line in the Chart
            If the X-axis is Sheet("Record").Column A Then 
                 Extend the line (Column A and its own Column) down to myRow
            End If
          Next Line
    
    Next
 Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works by modifying the formulaR1C1 for each series. For example

if `formulaR1C1 = "=SERIES("Weight",,Record!R38C1:R2281C1,Record!R38C8:R2281C8,1)"` then

`ar = Split(ser.FormulaR1C1, "R")`

will create an array of strings
`("=SE","IES("Weight",,","ecord!","38C1:","2281C1,","ecord!","38C8:","2281C8,1")`.

The last element `ar(ubound(ar))` is `2281C8,1`. Split that on`C` and the first element is `2281`. Replace that row number with the new row number with `Replace(ser.FormulaR1C1, ":R" & r & "C", ":R" & myRow & "C")`

In case there are problems, a file is created called `debug.log` in the same directory as the workbook.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, cht As ChartObject, n As Integer, dt As Date
    Dim myLastRow As Integer, myRow As Integer
        
    Sheets("Record").Select
    
    ' Go to last entry
    myLastRow = ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    myLastRow = Range("H" & myLastRow).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("D" & myLastRow).Select   ' Don't ask !
        
    ' Extend Column A so that the last entry is a week from today.
    '  Also extend predictions
    
    myRow = myLastRow
    Do Until Range("A" & myRow) >= Now() + 7
        myRow = myRow + 1
        Range("A" & myRow) = Range("A" & myRow - 1) + 1
        If myRow > myLastRow + 1 Then
            Range("B" & myRow & ":G" & myRow).Value2 = Range("B" & myRow - 1 & ":G" & myRow - 1).Value2
        End If
    Loop
     
    dt = Date + 7
    
    ' log file for debugging
    Dim fso, ts
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.createTextFile("debug.log")

    Dim ser As Series, ar, r As Long
    Dim sOld As String, sNew As String
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each cht In ws.ChartObjects
            cht.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = dt
            ' For every line in the Chart
            ' extend the data range to myRow
            For Each ser In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection
                ' determine existing last row
                sOld = ser.FormulaR1C1
                ts.writeLine ser.Name & vbTab & ser.ChartType & vbTab & ser.Type
                ts.writeLine "Old: " & sOld
                ar = Split(ser.FormulaR1C1, "R")
                r = Split(ar(UBound(ar)), "C")(0)
                ts.writeLine UBound(ar) & vbTab & r & vbTab & myRow
                
                sNew = Replace(ser.FormulaR1C1, ":R" & r & "C", ":R" & myRow & "C")
                ts.writeLine "New: " & sNew & vbCrLf

                ' update series
                ser.FormulaR1C1 = sNew
              Next
        Next
     Next
     ts.Close
     MsgBox "Extended from row " & r & " to row " & myRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, CDP1802 - that looks pretty good & easy to follow - but I would NEVER have managed to do that by myself !
But - sorry - you got in there before I realised I had omitted something, and added another line to my question !
So there is a little tweak needed - but Alas! beyond my competence  :-(
Also . . . my version doesn't recognise your "Split ( )", so I guess you have a function that I don't have ?

Comment: I also don't have your "Replace" Function.
So I have had another go - but it fails at the last hurdle !

Comment: Yes, I know - you don't have some of those Functions of mine !  And "Comments" don't accept CrLf !  Sorry.  I hope you can make sense of it  :-(

Comment: It falls over at . . . . ser.FormulaR1C1 = (Quoted(myTest))

Comment: @Robin Can you post an example of `ser.FormulaR1C1`. Replace is a VBA function.

Comment: ser.FormulaR1C1 = (myTest) does not work, when myText = "=SERIES("Weight",,Record!R38C1:R2281C1,Record!R38C8:R2281C8,1)"

Comment: "Replace" doesn't work because your "Split" doesn't work for me  :-(

Comment: @Robin I have updated my post with more details and a debug.log. Split  and Replace are standard VBA functions. You may have to provide a copy of the workbook on a dropbox for me to investigate further,

Comment: Thank you again, CDP1802 !  My apologies for not responding sooner - "been a bit busy"  ;-)  I have gone through your script and understand it - though I could never have hoped to write it !  WAY beyond my competence !  I have  copied your script into the worksheet, but haven't yet dared to run it because    . . . . sorry . . .   there needs to be an  IF  in there somewhere, for this routine should not apply to a few Charts that do not have, as their X-axis, "Sheets("Record").Range("A . . . .

Comment: Thank you, CDP1802.  I'm a (retired) Civil Engineer.  When I started training, 52 years ago, our first lecture started with - "You are here to learn to become Civil Engineers.  That means you will NOT be experts at anything; but you will learn WHEN to call in an experts, AND you will understand what they say."  A lesson I learned !  ;-)